# Monitoring more VMs without installing a Agent, i tried it with to connect it with macros

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, devops, monitoring, zabbix

I have 30 VMs, and I don't want to install an agent on them, such as a Zabbix Agent or SNMP Agent. I've heard that it's possible to monitor VMs without installing an agent using simple checks or something similar. Can somebody explain this to me or help me?

I tried a way and get this error: "Cannot find the host interface 'NAME' for the data point key '**vmware.eventlog[{$VMWARE.URL},all]**."

`{$VMWARE.PASSWORD} password {$VMWARE.USERNAME} administrator {$VMWARE.URL} https://@IPadress/sdk`

I read the Zabbix documentation, but the section on 'Simple Checks' doesn't explain it in detail.

I Try to configure a Remotless Agent for the VM but they dont Accept my way, so it came this error vmware.eventlog[{$VMWARE.URL},all]